# Have to tap twice to fire event/link with iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html

Why is it that, with regular link tags (`<a>`), you have to tap twice for them to fire with iOS devices?

For example, I have the following in my code:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="link">Google</a>
```

On iOS, I have to tap that link twice for it to redirect me.

In other cases, I have links that are fired through some jQuery event, which also require you to tap twice to fire the event.

How can I fix this, knowing that this is a large project?

Thanks.

Comment: Please give us code sniper or working example in jsfiddle

Comment: Regular hyperlinks should just require a single tap.  If you're tapping twice, there is likely something else in the way.  I would start by looking for `ev.preventDefault()` or `return false` in some of your click handlers.

Comment: @RyanWheale I think it might be the hover effects that might be causing the issue.

Comment: The point is, if you [paste the code you gave us into a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/s12L4xqe/) and pull it up on iOS, it works.  How are we supposed to help you if you don't give us a live example or something more to work with?

Comment: @RyanWheale But that link doesn't work on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

try to add `touchend` event with your click like :

```
$('#anchor').on('click touchend', function(e) {

    window.location = 'link';
});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that, if a certain link on my page has a jQuery event that is fired when it's clicked, this will start both that event as well as your event.

Comment: try this, but not tested
$('#anchor').on('touchend', function(e) { $(this).click();});

Comment: That didn't work. It clicked it even when I simply scrolled down the page (not tapping).

Comment: you can check for touchmove event
var move = false;
$("body").on("touchmove", function(){
  move = true;
});
$('#anchor').on('touchend', function(e) { 
if (move)
      return;
$(this).click();});

Comment: don't forget to reset move variable on touch start:
$("body").on("touchstart", function(){
    move = false;
});